# Where to store Nautilus-Actions .desktop files?

Tags: gnome, nautilus

I'd like to create a new Nautilus action for selected files, but I'm stumped as to where to put the action information itself. `nautilus-actions-new --desktop` [segfaults](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/nautilus-list/2011-November/msg00001.html), `nautilus-actions-config-tool` just prints `Trace/breakpoint trap` and returns exit code 133, and there doesn't seem to be any references in the `man` pages to **where Nautilus-internal .desktop files should be installed**, any tips or alternative ways to **customize the Nautilus context menu**.

Answer (score 1):

I may not be getting your question and I couldn't reproduce the segmentation fault on Debian squeeze using `nautilus 2.30.1` and `nautilus-actions 2.30.2` either. I'm not sure also what you mean by `Nautilus-internal .desktop files` but I understand you mean where nautilus actions stores the actions themselves.

They aren't stored in a particular file. They're actually stored in GConf and you can see them and edit them using `Configuration Editor` or from the command line installing package `gconf2` (Debian) and using command `gconftool-2`. You can find them under `/apps/nautilus-actions/configurations/` path.

Comment: I came here while trying to find out where Nautilus stores nautilus actions, on Ubuntu 14.04 with Nautilus 3.10.1. I couldn't find them in GConf, for example `gconftool-2 --dump /apps /desktop /schemas /system | grep -C 50 nautilus` returned nothing...

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in nautilus actions that was fixed recently (at least in 3.2).  The latest version is 3.2.2.

Regarding to customize Nautilus contextual menu, you can create use your own scripts or an extension in Python/C.

**Scripts:**

Those are stored in *.gnome2/scripts*.  The name of script will be the text that will appear in the contextual menu (under Scripts).  You can find more information in [Nautilus Scripts user guide](http://library.gnome.org/users/user-guide/2.32/gosnautilus-444.html.en).  Notice that *nautilus* 3 will also read the directory *.gnome2/scripts*.

**Extensions:**

Even though you can write extensions either in Python or C, Python is more straightforward for your needs.

Below a template you can use to create your own custom menu for Nautilus 3. It is based in [Postr's nautilus extension](http://git.gnome.org/browse/postr).  For Nautilus 3, you need to store it in *~/.local/share/nautilus-python/extensions*.

```python
from gi.repository import Nautilus, GObject
import os, os.path
from urllib import unquote

PROGRAM_NAME = '/path/to/the/program/you/want/to/run/with/the/files/selected'

class MyExtension(GObject.GObject, Nautilus.MenuProvider):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def action_for_my_files(self, menu, files):
        # This is the method invoked when our extension is activated
        # Do whatever you want to do with the files selected
        if len(files) == 0:
            return

        names = [ unquote(file.get_uri()[7:]) for file in files ]

        argv = [ PROGRAM_NAME ] + names

        GObject.spawn_async(argv, flags=GObject.SPAWN_SEARCH_PATH)

    def get_file_items(self, window, files):
        ''' This method is invoked to create a contextual menu.
            We can filter out the files, directories we do not want a menu
        '''

        '''No files selected -> no menu'''
        if len(files) == 0:
            return

        for fd in files:
            ''' Not a file -> no menu '''
            if fd.is_directory() or fd.get_uri_scheme() != 'file':
                return
            ''' Not an image -> no menu '''
            if not fd.is_mime_type("image/*"):
                return

        item = Nautilus.MenuItem(name='MyExtension::MethodUniqueId',
                                 label='Label in the menu...',
                                 tip='Tip for the menu',
                                 icon='icon_name')
        item.connect('activate', self.action_for_my_files, files)

        return item,
```

For Nautilus 2, the beginning the script is more or less the same. You only need to change the beginning.  For the previous example, it would be:

```python
import gobject, nautilus
import os, os.path
from urllib import unquote

PROGRAM_NAME = '/path/to/the/program/you/want/to/run/with/the/files/selected'

class PostrExtension(nautilus.MenuProvider):
...
```